# Misaligned objects in DIV

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a rectangular-shaped gray div that is supposed to hold a header ("sample text") and a thin turquoise highlight (which is also just a thin rectangle).  When I have both the turquoise div and header inside the other div, one gets forced out.

First of all, how can I fix this issue?  Also, is there a more efficient way for me to make the turquoise highlight in the gray div?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mXTR.png (if I have HTML as shown)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mXTR.png#1 (if I remove the turquoise div)

```
<div class="column w2">
    <div id="headerbox">
        <div class="highlightbox">
        </div>
    <h3>sample text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note I'm using some Sass CSS here:

```
h3 {
font: $header-type-font;
font-family: $header-type-font;
color: $header-type-color;
text-align: center;
}

#headerbox {
background-color: $box-color;
height: $block-height;
width: 400px;
}

.highlightbox {
background-color: $highlight-color;
height: $block-height;
width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: The output CSS is more use then the SCSS.

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `float:left` to your **`highlightbox`** class:

```
.highlightbox {
    background-color: $highlight-color;
    height: $block-height;
    width: 20px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Example, http://jsfiddle.net/gL9vbm2h/